# Why this multiset print code results forever loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, multiset

I want to print out every duplicates from a multiset, but somehow iterators behave strangely for me. How can fix this code? This code results a forever loop, that surprise me.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

static void print_duplicate(const std::multiset<int>& mset)
{
  std::stringstream error_msg;
  for (auto it = mset.begin(); it != mset.end(); ++it)
    {
      unsigned count = mset.count(*it);
      if (count < 2)
        continue;

      error_msg << "Duplicated numbers found:\n";

      for (unsigned i = 0; i < count; ++it, ++i)
        error_msg << "\tNum:" << *it << "\n";
    }

  std::cout << error_msg.str();
}

int main()
{
  std::multiset<int> mset;

  // fill it
  mset.insert(1);
  mset.insert(1);
  mset.insert(1);

  print_duplicate(mset);
}
```

**EDIT**
I added a --it at he end of the cycle

```
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < count; ++it, ++i)
    error_msg << "\tNum:" << *it << "\n";
  --it; // this line fix it
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for (unsigned i = 0; i < count; ++it, ++i)` When this loop ends, `it` will be equal to `mset.end()` and since you still have the other `++it` from the main loop, you are getting something different to `mset.end()` hence the program never ends.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your outer loop you might increment `it` more than once. Thus, the condition `it != mset.end()` might never be true, because the end has already been skipped. Incrementing a past-the-end iterator is undefined behavior, meaning it might also fail silently.

A possible solution might be to also check `it != mset.end()` in the inner `for`-loop:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; (i < count) && (it != mset.end()); ++it, ++i)
    error_msg << "\tNum:" << *it << "\n";
```

Comment: This result a forever loop for me

Comment: Yes, just put ``--it`` after this loop ends.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you slip past the end without detecting it. In the `mset` you create, there are only `1`s. This means `count` will be 3 and the nested `for` (the one over `i`) will execute 3 times; when it finishes, `it` will be equal to `mset.end()`. Then control reaches the end of the outer `for` and `it` is incremented, becoming illegal and, more importantly, different from `mset.end()`. Which means the outer loop never terminates.

Answer (score 1):

Quick Fix: Add an extra line after the inner loop: it--;

Reason is explained in Angew's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the for loop to this:

```
for(std::container::iterator it=mset.begin(), it_next=it; it!=mset.end(); it=it_next) {
  ++it_next;
  ...
}
```

Essentially, you are skipping past the end of the loop because you are checking the variable against your iterator. Incrementing only the secondary iterator will prevent this from happening.